# Authentication before call jira.issueviews:issue-xml

Tags: google-sheets, xml-parsing, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-agile

I usually access some ticket information from my company's Jira using the `issue view:issue-xml` method, directly from my browser.

```
https://mycompany.atlassian.net/si/jira.issueviews:issue-xml/TICKET-123/TICKET-123.xml
```

Now I am trying to access the same information by Google Sheets but, correctly, the application can't authenticate to Jira and the consequence is that I can't open the same address.

Can I authenticate myself by accessing the same methods? Something like passing a username/password in the parameters of the URL or (better) a token ID in the URL as well.

My final target is to use the APIs endpoint to Google Sheets and import with the function [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en).

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I have 3 questions. 1. What is `application` of `the application can't authenticate to Jira`? 2. What is `same methods` of `Can I authenticate myself by accessing the same methods?` 3. About `My final target is to use the APIs endpoint to Google Sheets and import with the function IMPORTXML.`, can I ask you about the specification of the request to your API? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: No problem for the English . 1. Google Sheets; 2. the method is "jira.issueviews:issue-xml" I don't know any method to authenticate; 3. the request is to open the posted link.

Comment: @Tanaike Basically, my target is to open from Google Sheets the following link "https://mycompany.atlassian.net/si/jira.issueviews:issue-xml/TICKET-123/TICKET-123.xml" and get the ticket information.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `the method is "jira.issueviews:issue-xml" I don't know any method to authenticate`, can you provide the official document of the authorization for requesting your API?